# Postback in ASP.net page causing delay after two clicks

Tags: asp.net, delay, postback

I have a asp.net page that works all good and fast in local host. But as I publish the page after two clicks of postback through a button it delays for 1-2 minutes
A simple button like

```
<asp: Button runat="server" Text="Button" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
```

also delays after two two clicks for 1-2 minutes

Comment: Not really enough information here to guess, anymore than you stating your car will not start, and we don't know why? So, what kind of hosting, does the site hit some database? Is there network(s) involved on this system? Does the site pull data or talk to any other system? Or are you talking about a one plain jane web page with a simple button that does say a debug.print on the server?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred due to **Firewall rules**. Disabling that rules all went fine. It was expecting my application is using

```
http-video
```

or a

```
Web-crawler
```